# How to see if ... ellipses in R contains a certain argument?

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

I'm writing a wrapper for the YouTube Analytics API, and have created a function as follows:

```
yt_request <- function(dimensions = NULL, metrics = NULL, sort = NULL,
                    maxResults = NULL, filtr = NULL, startDate = Sys.Date() - 30,
                                endDate = Sys.Date(), token) {
  
  url <- paste0("https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?",
                "&ids=channel%3D%3DMINE",
                "&startDate=", startDate, 
                "&endDate=", endDate)
  
  if(!is.null(dimensions)) url <- paste0(url, "&dimensions=", dimensions)
  if(!is.null(metrics))    url <- paste0(url, "&metrics=", metrics)
  if(!is.null(sort))       url <- paste0(url, "&sort=", sort)
  if(!is.null(maxResults)) url <- paste0(url, "&maxResults=", maxResults)
  if(!is.null(filtr))      url <- paste0(url, "&filters=", filtr)
  
  r <- GET(url, token)
  return(r)
}
```

This is meant to just be a flexible but not the most friendly of functions because I want to have wrapper functions that will contain `yt_request()` that will be much more user friendly. For example:

```
top_videos <- function(...) {
  dim <- "video"
  met <- "views,averageViewDuration"
  maxRes <- 10

  temp <- yt_request(dimensions = dim, metrics = met, maxResults = maxRes, token = myToken)
  return(temp)
}
```

Which so far works fine and dandy, but I also want potential users to have a little flexibility with the results. For example, if they want to have `maxResults <- 20` instead of 10 or they want different metrics than the ones I specify, I want them to be able to pass their own arguments in the `...` of `top_videos(...)`.

How can I do a check if someone passes an argument in the ellipsis? If they pass a metric, I want it to override the default I specify, otherwise, go with the default.

EDIT

To help clarify, I'm hoping that when the user decides to use the function, they could just write something like `top_videos(maxResults = 20)` and the function would ignore the line `maxRes <- 10` and in the `yt_request()` function would assign `maxResults = 20` instead of 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can capture the `...` in a `list` and convert the whole elements to a key/value pair. Then, extract the elements based on the name.  If we are not passing that particular named element, it will return `NULL`.  We make use of this behavior of `NULL` to concatenate with the default value of 10 in `maxRes` and select the first element (`[1]`) so that if it is NULL, the default 10 is selected, or else the value passed will be selected.  Likewise, do this on all those objects that the OP wanted to override

```
top_videos <- function(...) {

    nm1 <- list(...)
      lst1 <- as.list(nm1)
      
      dim <- c(lst1[["dimensions"]], "video")[1]
       met <- c(lst1[["metrics"]], "views,averageViewDuration")[1]
       maxRes <- c(lst1[['maxResults']], 10)[1]
       
       #temp <- yt_request(dimensions = dim, 
            metrics = met, maxResults = maxRes, token = myToken)
       #temp
       maxRes
      }
```

-testing

```
top_videos(maxResults = 20)
#[1] 20
      
  top_videos(hello = 5)
#[1] 10
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the person specifies all three metrics? the ```...``` would have to contain arguments for ```dim```, ```met```, and ```maxRes``` right? what if they only specified ```maxRes```, then the first element of the ```nm1``` list is the value that should be for ```maxRes``` but instead gets assigned to ```dim```?

Comment: @Jacob The `lst` that is captured will be named list if you are passing `top_videos(dim = 'something', maxres = 2)` etc i.e. it will be converted to `lst1 <- list(dim = 'something', maxres = 2)`  Then, you may use the names of the lst1 i.e. `lst1[['dim']]` or `lst1[['maxres]]` for extraction.  The one thing I am not sure is how you want this to override

Comment: I added an edit to the question that hopefully is helpful. I just want my default ```dim```,```met```, and ```maxRes``` to be the strings that are passed to ```yt_request()``` IF the user doesn't add an argument. If they specify ```top_videos(maxResults=20)``` then I want to completely ignore my original line saying ```maxRes <- 10``` and push that 20 forward, so then the request function becomes ```yt_request(dimensions = dim, metrics = met, maxResults=20)```. Does that help? I'd want the user to specify the argument name of ```yt_request()``` like maxResults instead of overwrite the maxRes.

Comment: @Jacob Try the update in my post.  The idea is that if you don't pass that argument, the `lst1[['maxResults"]]` will be NULL, so `c(lst1[["maxResults"]], maxRes)[1]` will get the 10 value, or else, it will override the `maxRes` and we select the first value of 20

Comment: @Jacob can you check the update.  It does update according to what you meentioned

Comment: Fantastic! Works just as I was hoping.